# Hiding an Specific Row from Select MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
       $SQL = "SELECT id, ciudadh, corporacionh,r1,ultima,anotaciones FROM juan ".$where." AND ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start ,$limit";
```

So I have a row with id=500 and I want to hide that row from that query.

How I do that?

Comment: no, I want to hide the row not select that. edit: oh the "!" means "not this" ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another where clause:

```
$SQL = "SELECT id
              ,ciudadh
              ,corporacionh
              ,r1
              ,ultima
              ,anotaciones 
        FROM juan ".$where
     ." AND id!=500
        ORDER BY $sidx $sord 
        LIMIT $start ,$limit";
```